# Initialising a C++ library in Arduino

Tags: c++, constructor, arduino, sensors, motion

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/tcleg/Six_Axis_Complementary_Filter) six axis complementary filter library to interpret data from the [LSM6DS3 motion sensor](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_LSM6DS3_Arduino_Library).

Calling it inside my Arduino sketch, I get this error. Sorry for the dumb question, I'm just starting out learning this:

```
#include "SparkFunLSM6DS3.h" 
#include "Wire.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "six_axis_comp_filter.h"


LSM6DS3 myIMU; // Constructor for the motion sensor (this works)
CompSixAxis test; // this breaks
```

when I try to initialise an instance of the CompSixAxis class it gives me this error:

**no matching function for call to 'CompSixAxis::CompSixAxis()'**

Comment: seems like that class has no default constructor (ie. one taking zero arguments). In that case you have to call the correct constructor

Comment: @tobi303: A default c'tor is a c'tor that can be called without passing any arguments. That is not the same as a c'tor that takes no arguments at all. Irrespective of that, `CompSixAxis` doesn't have a default c'tor.

Comment: @IInspectable usually I am the one who does the nitpicking ;) However, I am always glad to be corrected. Unfortunately to late to edit the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `CompSixAxis` dose not have a default constructor.  This means you cannot use it like

```
CompSixAxis test;
```

As that requires a default constructor.  In order to construct the object you will need to use the constructor with the form

```
CompSixAxis(float deltaTime, float tau);
```

So your updated code would look like

```
CompSixAxis test(some_value, some_other_value);
```

Comment: When I put the new code in place of the "defaul constructor" I get an error saying: 

_error: expected unqualified-id before 'float'
 CompSixAxis(float deltaTime, float tau);_

Thank you for taking the time, Nathan!

Comment: @VladyVeselinov I updated the answer to show how you would call it.